# How do i move a file located at the same place as my batch script to somewhere else?

Tags: batch-processing

I want my batch file to move a second file located at the same place.

I did the easiest method, which is `move uninstall.bat "destination"` but returns "System cannot find targeted file"

So I did this: `move "%~dp0\uninstall.bat" "C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"`, but it still can't find the file.

Comment: `move "%~dp0filename.ext" "destination"` The quote should come after the filename, not before. Adding a backslash usually also works: `move "%~dp0\filename.ext" "destination"`.

Comment: thank you but it's still not working, the command is `move "%~dp0\uninstall.bat" "C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"`, is the `{username}` wrong ?

Comment: You should edit your question and include the _exact_ script and the _exact_ output.

Comment: Change `{username}` to `%USERNAME%` will always use the name of the current logged on user.

Comment: When using `%APPDATA%`, you can even copy to `"%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"`, because `%APPDATA%` normally contains `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming`